# Trying to find the correct way to a simple Docker container in Gitlab CI/CD

Tags: git, docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I've got a simple setup.

1. Linux host for running all containers
2. Gitlab in a Docker container
3. Gitlab runner in another Docker container already registered in the Gitlab

My code is a Flask app and I want to run it in a Docker container created by Gitlab. Each time I push changes to Gitlab repo I need:

1. Remove previous running Flask container
2. Create new Docker container for Flask app
3. Copy project folder from Gitlab repo to Flask container
4. Run this new container

Questions.

1. Should I deploy K8S anywhere as soon as I only need 1 container? I guess I don't need it for that simple setup.
2. Should I use Docker compose or I just need .gitlab-ci.yml and Dockerfile and that's all?
3. What should I set in the .gitlab-ci.yml to remove the previous container?

Thank you.